# Memory leak in JspWriterImpl in JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jboss, jboss7.x

On a customer system we have JBoss AS 7.1.3 with our app deployed. After every few days of active usage we experience OOM error.

In heap dump I can see that 42% of memory is occupied by `org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl` class:
[image]

The problem looks similar to [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI24001) and [this](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2011-1318/).

So the question is: how to resolve this memory leak? Unfortunately changing application server is not an option here.

**Update**: there are a lot of custom tags in the project, and they have code like this:

```
        try
        {
            JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
            out.print(page);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.error(ex);
        }
```

Comment: How many characters in your jsp file? looks like you have huge jsp files.

Comment: Do you actually release variables? Does every variable have a know start and end point of life? Could it be that variables remain living in a list so they don't get gc()'d  and keep on living along never to be accessed again? Just clean up your variables properly. Know when, where and how they die.

Comment: My guess is that the application is holding a reference to the JspWriter (or maybe the response itself) after the request / response is finished.

Comment: @laidbackengineer Most of the JSP files are less the 10Kb. There are some ~100Kb, but only few, and rarely used.

Comment: @michael-dibbets Unfortunately it's a huge ~10M LoC project developed by different teams. So it's not possible in this case.

Comment: Then I have really bad news for you. Someone screwed up and dit not watch his/her variables or stole someone elses variables without cleaning up. Two choices. start over, or go through it with a dustcomb tracking all variables, seeing where they end up and where they reach EOL such with that much data to process but thats the only way. There are tools to help, but with that much stuff happening its still hell

Comment: @ Lance Java see my update to the question

Comment: Try setting the out to null when you are done. before exiting the scope do out = null; so the reference is clear.

Comment: @dds I am also seeing similar  issue with my application.in JspWriterImpl i am seeing page html string.Have you got any fix for this issue? Thanks,Paul.

Comment: @PaulErric no, we just migrated to Wildfly, issue was solved.

Comment: Thanks dds,.We can't upgrade the server .I am Struck at this point.Will keep you posted if I get any fix for the same.Thanks,Paul.

Comment: Hello. I am also facing the same issue with WildFly 18.0.1 and it sounds related to custom tags too. Any hint how to detect the exact tag involved in trouble?